# Class wrapping a function: get correct typings and access to number of arguments (in typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, wrapper

I wrote a little class which wraps a specified function and also takes a list of validation patterns for each function argument. This class has a `call` function which should take the same arguments as the input function, validate those, call the input function, and wrap the result e.g. into a rxjs/Observable. Hence, the constructor should check if the number of arguments specified by the function `method.length` is the same as the number of validation patterns.

The raw javascript version should look something like this:

```
class Wrapper {
    method;
    validationPatterns;

    constructor(method, validationPatterns) {
        if (method.length !== validationPatterns.length) {
            // throw error
        }
        this.method = method;
        this.validationPatterns = validationPatterns;
    }

    validate(...args) {
        this.validationPatterns.forEach(pattern => {
            // apply validation pattern
        });
    }

    call(...args) {
        // validate arguments
        this.validate(...args);
        // run method and wrap its result e.g. in an Observable
        const methodResult = this.method(...args);
        return Observable.of(methodResult);
    }
}
```

Now I googled a lot and tried different things to apply correct types to this class. But I could not find an approach, which lets me

1. access the number of function parameters (via `method.length`) inside the constructor. So it is not possible to construct a class instance with false validation.
2. and at the same time have correct typings for all class functions.

I tried the following things:

### 1. Using `<T extends Function>`

**Pros:**

- I can access the specified method inside the class and on class
  instances with the correct types.

**Cons:**

- There is no way, to extract the parameter types and return type out
  of `T` and apply them to `validate()` and `call()`. They still have
  to use the types `any`/`any[]`.

*Code Sample:*

```
class Wrapper<F extends Function> {

    constructor(public method: F, public validationPatterns: any[]) {
        if (method.length !== validationPatterns.length) {
            // throw error
        }
    }

    validate(...args: any[]): void {
        // ...
    }

    call(...args: any[]): any {
        // ...
    }
}
```

### 2. Using a single function parameter.

**Pros:**

- This way, it is possible to apply correct types to all functions.

**Cons:**

- Functions which need more than one argument, need to wrap those inside a correctly typed tuple or object. This requires additional syntax (e.g. brackets `[a, b]`) when writing and calling the method. But this should still be acceptable.
- However, we cannot check the number of validation patterns, because `method.length == 1`. Hence, for the sake of complete typing, we would have to concede functionality drawbacks, which does not sound good to me.

*Code Sample:*

```
class Wrapper<T, U> {
    constructor(public method: (arg: T) => U, public validationPatterns: any[]) {
        // CANNOT check correct number of validation patterns
    }

    validate(args: T): void {
        // ...
    }

    call(args: T): Observable<U> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

### 3. Overloading

Since the wrapped functions will usually only have a few parameters, in another approach, we could try to use function overloading. However, so far, I only found information about overloading a single function. I guess, what I actually want is an overloaded class where the signatures of `call()` and `validate()` depend on the constructor overload.

I have no experience with overloading in typescript, but I guess a code sample with independently overloaded functions could look something like this:

```
class Wrapper<F extends Function, T1, T2, T3, U> {

    constructor(method: (arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3) => U, validationPatterns: any[]);
    constructor(method: (arg1: T1, arg2: T2) => U, validationPatterns: any[]);
    constructor(method: (arg1: T1) => U, validationPatterns: any[]);
    constructor(method: () => U, validationPatterns: any[]);
    constructor(public method: F, public validationPatterns: any[]) {
        // ...
    }

    validate(arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3): void;
    validate(arg1: T1, arg2: T2): void;
    validate(arg1: T1): void;
    validate(): void;
    validate(...args: any[]): void {
        // ...
    }

    call(arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3): Observable<U>;
    call(arg1: T1, arg2: T2): Observable<U>;
    call(arg1: T1): Observable<U>;
    call(): Observable<U>;
    call(...args: any[]): Observable<U> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

## Questions

- Is there a way to get both: complete typing AND access to the function's number of argument?
- Is it possible to use overloading the way I intend?
- Which approach do you recommend me to go? I currently go with the first one (`<T extends Function>`) which has full functionality but missing types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overload classes but it is a bit more complicated, you need to declare the overloads separately and define a constructor for each overload:

```
class WrapperImpl {

    constructor(public method: Function, public validationPatterns?: Function[]) {
        // ...
    }
    validate(...args: any[]): void {
        // ...
    }

    call(...args: any[]): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<any>();
    }
}


type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends any ? keyof T: never;
type IsValid<T, TResult> = KeysOfUnion<T> extends never ?  never : TResult;
const Wrapper: {
    new <U>  (m: ()=> U, ) :  {
        validate(): void
        call(): Observable<U>
    }
    new <T1, U>  (m: (a: T1)=> U, validationPatterns: [IsValid<T1, (a: T1)=>boolean>]) :  {
        validate(a: T1): void
        call(a: T1): Observable<U>
    }
    new <T2, T1, U>  (m: (a: T1, a2: T2)=> U, validationPatterns: [IsValid<T1, (a: T1)=>boolean>, IsValid<T2, (a: T2)=>boolean>]) :  {
        validate(a: T1, a2: T2): void
        call(a: T1, a2: T2): Observable<U>
    }
    // Add more as needed 
} = WrapperImpl

let w = new Wrapper(() => "");
w.call() // return Observable<string>

let w2 = new Wrapper((n: number) => "", [n=> true]);
w2.call(10) // return Observable<string>
```

I would not bother too much with generics in the implementation, you will need to use very general types anyway (ie `Function` and `any`) generics will not help you much there. The calls will be correctly typed and checked and that is important part.

I assumed the validations are functions, and you can get inference and type safety on those as well. I had to use a bit of conditional type magic to get the compiler to select the correct overload for each number of parameters but it seems to work well. If you have any issues let me know.

This approach still has at least one drawback, when used with functions with optional parameters as the optional parameters become required:

```
function withOpt(n?: number) { return ""}
let w3 = new Wrapper(withOpt, [n=> true]);
w3.call(1) // 1 is required.
```

Comment: Great Answer! Exactly what I need. Actually, my validators are not functions but objects of `any` type given as argument into a check function, so, I don't even need the `type` declarations.One little thing: vscode showed an error when I used `public method: Function` (Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '() => any'). I have to use `<F extends Function>` to make it work.